# Restricted Witt algebra and analog of Fermat's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory, lie-algebras

I found this interesting result in the work of [D. B. Fuchs and T. Evans(2002)](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0111271), and also I have proved this result using Bell polynomials. However, I suppose that there should be more easier solution. Any ideas?

Let $D=f\frac{d}{dx}$ be an operator and $f$ be a function of $x$, so

$D^{p-2}(f)+\frac{d^{p-2}}{dx^{p-2}}\left(f^{p-1}(x)\right)\equiv 0\;(mod\; p)$

Comment: I assume the $f$ in $D$ is the same as in $f$?